# Why v.0.10.25 when installing node.js v5 using package manager on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Node.js v5 on Ubuntu 14.04 via package manager as follows, but running 'node --version' showed v.0.10.25. Why it is not the current v.5.8 stable?

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: You download version 5 with curl, then download an install whatever comes back with `apt-get` separately?

Comment: Followed [instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) on Node.js site.

Comment: You need to remove the [default Node.js package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/nodejs) that comes with Ubuntu 14.04, first...

Answer (score 0):

In turned out the reason is because Google just discontinued 32-bit Google Chrome for Linux. Solution is to modify source.list file for Chrome, as described in this [post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu).